# .php files not working with AddHandler - Apache 2.4

Tags: php5, apache-2.4

I am having an issue with Apache 2.4 configuration with PHP5. I have got this:

```
<Directory / >
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

  Action backButton /backButton.cgi
  AddHandler backButton .html .htm .php
</Directory>
```

It works for both `.html` and `.htm` files (i.e. `backButton.cgi` runs) but not for `.php`. I have tried everything I can find on the topic including just having `.php` (i.e `AddHandler backButton .php`).

If there is any extra information required please ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have this set:

```
Action add-footer /script.pl
AddHandler add-footer .html .htm .php
```

Which seems odd to me. What is `add-footer`? What is `script.pl`? That seems to be an example from the [Apache site](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html) that would cause requests for files with the html extension to trigger the launch of the footer.pl CGI script. Why would you need that?

Seems like that should be:

```
AddHandler php5-script php
```

So your whole `Directory` directive should be:

```
<Directory / >
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
  AddHandler php5-script php
</Directory>
```

**EDIT:** Since the original poster does want the `add-footer` functionality—now called `backButton`—it seems that this configuration would be the best way to handle; combine what I am doing above with with the original poster posted to begin with:

```
<Directory / >
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  AddHandler php5-script .php

  Action backButton /backButton.cgi
  AddHandler backButton .html .htm .php
</Directory>
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:** Seems like there was a typo the first time with me setting `php` instead of `.php` for `AddHandler php5-script .php`.  But also, try this instead using `application/x-httpd-php5` instead of `php5-script`:

```
<Directory / >
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

  Action backButton /backButton.cgi
  AddHandler backButton .html .htm .php
</Directory>
```

Comment: Sorry, your right. I can see where you are coming from. This is indeed of the Apache site but I forgot to change it to my situation. The name `add-footer` in my case is `backButton` and `/script.pl` is `/backButton.cgi` (which is a bash script). I have edited the post above.

What I am trying to do is to add some html content to every .html, .htm and .php page in a specific directory. The catch is I can't edit the pages. The solution above does exactly what I want for .html and .htm pages but not .php pages. The .php page itself runs fine but the extra content is not added.

Comment: @JamesStewy Oh, okay. Then look at my latest edit.  Combine what I am doing with what you are attempting to do & it should work.

Comment: So, I added `AddHandler php5-script php` to my example in the original post and it didn't make a difference. The php page loads but the html isn't added in.

Comment: Hmmm… How about `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php` Look at my edit. Made a typo previously as well.

Comment: No difference...

Comment: @JamesStewy Sorry. Did my best.